# Querying across a time range

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have the need to query events stored in our table across a time range. A user could ask for events from a specfic time in one day, to another specfic time in another day.

We have been thinking about creating our partition key as a truncated value, possibly the day. That way with one query we could get a full day of events and then do some client side filtering for the specfic time range using the full time attribute.

Now this may be a problem if we have to query across multiple days, meaning multiple queries. A day could habe anything from a few thousand events, to a couple of hundred thousand.

Is the truncated timestamp (down to a day) the best approach, or is there a better one?

We were also wondering could there be a better aws serverless solution for us to use for this use case, while still using dynamodb for event storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve it is by having a static value as the gsi Partition key and a timestamp as the sort key.

| GSI1PK | GSI1SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01T00:00:000 | data |
| 1 | 2023-03-01T00:00:000 | data |
| 1 | 2023-04-01T00:00:000 | data |
| 1 | 2023-05-01T00:00:000 | data |

Now you can efficiently query for any data range, be it a specific minute of a day without filtering.

Be mindful that keeping a single value as a partition key of your index limits your writes to approx 1000 WCU per second. If you intend to scale beyond that, consider sharding that GSI value.

Comment: Thanks Lee! The 1000 WCU shouldn't be a problem. Am I right in thinking that even if we had hundreds of thousands of records in that partition key, dynamodb would be doing the heavy lifting with the sort key and still be able to respond within a sub-second response? I know we would have to handle pagination if the response was over 1mb, but apart from that?

Comment: DynamoDB provides single digit response for singleton operations, such as GetItem and PutItem. In this case you're using Query, which could take slightly longer depending on how many items are evaluated. But it's as efficient as you can be, only the items that are withing the specified time range are evaluated.